# JPEG images on showing in QTWebkit on Ubuntu

Tags: qt, webkit, jpeg, qtwebkit

We have a web browser app based on qt webkit. It works fine on windows and mac. But when we compile under Linux, we can't get it to show any JPEG images inside a webview on any websites. I did some google search and believe it might have something to do with the jpeg plugin for QT.

But I can't get jpeg images to show up even if we copy the image codecs to $exepath/plugins/imageformats/ and then create a qt.conf file under $exepath with the following content:

[Paths]
Plugins = plugins

On Windows & Mac, we didn't have to do anything for the debug version for the jpeg images to show up. We only have to copy the plugin dll and qt.conf file for the release version to be redistributed.

We tried both qt 4.7.4 and qt 4.8.1

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: How was Qt built for the platform?

Comment: try $exepath/imageformats/
works for me. in my case it was sql driver not detected in /plugins/sqldrivers but works fine in /sqldrivers. some defaults must have changed in those releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you running on desktop linux like Ubuntu than try installing system jpeg library. I think your Qt libraries compiled to work with system jpeg may be.

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62
```